# Applescript, "A class name can't go after this identifier error", what does it mean?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, automation, applescript

Someone tried to help me set up a keyboard macro using a program called keyboard maestro on macos to control youtube, his example had safari:

```
set tabURL to "YouTube.com"

    tell application "Safari"
        set windowsList to index of every window
        repeat with i in windowsList
            try
                tell window i
                    set current tab to (first tab whose URL contains tabURL)
                end tell
                set index of window i to 1
                exit repeat
            end try
        end repeat
    end tell
```

It worked, I simply changed the name safari to google chrome, I put in this code:

```
set tabURL to "YouTube.com"

tell application "Google Chrome"
    set windowsList to index of every window
    repeat with i in windowsList
        try
            tell window i
                set current tab to (first tab whose URL contains tabURL)
            end tell
            set index of window i to 1
            exit repeat
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
```

it gave me this error message

2020-09-10 15:02:26 Execute an AppleScript failed with script error: text-script:165:176: script error: A class name can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)

what does it mean? any help appreciated.

Comment: You would need to check the scripting dictionary of Google Chrome. Terminology is up to the developer - there is no guarantee that any given term does the same thing in different applications.

Comment: ok thanks for the clue, I'll try to get more information.

Comment: couldn't find anything in script editor or through google, weird.

Answer (score 2):

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with thisWindow in windows
        set cnt to 1
        repeat with thisTab in (tabs of thisWindow)
            if URL of thisTab contains "youtube.com" then
                set active tab index of thisWindow to cnt
                set index of thisWindow to 1
                                exit repeat
            end if
            set cnt to cnt + 1
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

this is the fix if anyone cares.